# Weak convergence of $L^2$ function which is continuous in time

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Suppose that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded and $f_n:\Omega\times [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\sup_{t\in[0,T]}\|f_n(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq 1$ and $\|f_n(s,\cdot)-f_n(t,\cdot))\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq |s-t|^{1/2}$. Thus I can find a weak convergent subsequence such that $\langle f_n,g\rangle_{L^2(0,T:L^2(\Omega))} \to \langle f,g\rangle_{L^2(0,T:L^2(\Omega))}$ for every $g(t,x)  \in L^2(0,T:L^2(\Omega))$.

How can I show that $\langle f_n(s,\cdot),h(\cdot)\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)} \to \langle f(s,\cdot),h(\cdot)\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}$ for every $s \in [0,T]$ and $h \in L^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: Maybe you could use Arzela Ascoli theorem, where $f_n$ is considered as map from $(0,T)$ into $L^2(\Omega)$ supplied with the weak topology.

Comment: If I use Arzela Ascoli theorem with the strong topology, I can get $\sup_t\|f_n-f\|_{L^2} \to 0$. But If I use Arzela Ascoli theorem with the weak topology, I can get $\sup_t|\langle f_n-f,g \rangle_{L^2} |\to 0$ uniform for $g$?

Comment: I would say yes, but maybe someone else knows better.

Comment: By comparing the value at $s$ with the average of the values on some short interval around $s$. Also be careful: weak limit in $L^2$ of the rectangle formally doesn't even allow you to talk about the values of the function on slices (those are of measure $0$) so, technically speaking, you should do some preliminary work to have them all defined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{t_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a dense subset of $[0,T].$ For example it may consist of all rational numbers in $[0,T].$ By the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, for every $0\le t\le T$ the sequence $f_n(t,\cdot)\in L^2(\Omega)$ contains a weakly convergent subsequence. By applying the diagonalization method, there is an increasing subsequence $n_m$ of natural numbers, such that $f_{n_m}(t_k,\cdot)$ is weakly convergent for every $k,$ as $m\to\infty.$

We will show that $f_{n_m}(t,\cdot) $ is weakly convergent for every $0\le t\le T.$
Fix $t$ and $h\in L^2(\Omega).$ We may assume that $\|h\|_2\le 1.$ It suffices to show that the sequence $\langle f_{n_m}(t,\cdot),h\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}.$ satisfies the Cauchy condition.  For $\delta>0$ there exists $t_k$ such that $|t-t_k|<\delta^2.$ Then for $h\in L^2(\Omega)$ we get
$$|\langle f_{n_m}(t,\cdot),h\rangle-\langle f_{n_l}(t,\cdot),h\rangle |  \le |\langle f_{n_m}(t,\cdot)-f_{n_m}(t_k,\cdot),h\rangle|\\ +|\langle f_{n_m}(t_k,\cdot),h\rangle-\langle f_{n_l}(t_k,\cdot),h\rangle | + |\langle f_{n_l}(t_k,\cdot)-f_{n_l}(t,\cdot),h\rangle|\\
\le 2\delta\|h\|_2+|\langle f_{n_m}(t_k,\cdot),h\rangle-\langle f_{n_l}(t_k,\cdot),h\rangle |$$ There exists $M$ such that for $l,m>M$ the last term is less than $\delta\|h\|_2.$ Summarizing, for $l,m>M$ we get
$$ |\langle f_{n_m}(t,\cdot),h\rangle-\langle f_{n_l}(t,\cdot),h\rangle | <3\delta\|h\|_2\le 3\delta$$
This completes the proof.

Once we have obtained a subsequence $f_{n_m},$ by applying the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, we can extract a subsequence $f_{n_{m_l}}$ convergent weakly in $L^2(0,T:L^2(\Omega)).$ In this way all the requirements are satisfied.